# Horizontal scroll appear in all user page

Tags: discussion, bug, design

All the [**user page**](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users) in webmasters site overflow with horizontal scroll bar, but those pages no need of that scroll bar. And I'm using updated Firefox browser on windows 7.  Is this normal ?

> [image]

Comment: Best place to file this [design] [bug] would be Webmaster's meta since it appears to be site-specific.

Comment: Reproduced using a few different browsers, going to ping devs about it Monday.

Comment: @TimPost any update on this issue ?, still not fixed ?

Comment: it's a known issue in quite a few sites, and on Jin's list.